# Deserialize duplicate name XML child nodes to C# object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have an XML Structure that should really have been an array, but is not structured this way. Here is a representation of the XML.

```
<rootElement>
    <foo>...</foo>
    <bar>...</bar>
    <bar>...</bar>
    <bar>...</bar>
</rootElement>
```

I cant seem to get `<bar>` to turn into an array. I have the following C# class to try and do this.

```
[XmlRoot("rootElement")]
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlArrayItem("bar")]
    public List<MyItems> Items { get; set; }
}
```

It doesnt work though. I know I could parse the XML using an XML Document and then convert it to a C# object this way but i would rather just use attributes on the C# class and quickly generate the object using XmlSerializer.

I have tried using a variation of attributes on the Items property such as XmlElement and XmlArray but i keep getting 0 items after deserializing. Is there a way this can be done using the XmlSerializer or do i have no other alternative than to use XmlDocument?

Comment: I can't answer about using `XmlSerializer`, but if you *do* go the route of manual deserialization, I'd strongly recommend using LINQ to XML (`XDocument` etc) rather than `XmlDocument`.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Please show how you de-serialize your object. I suppose if you don´t have the array as a further nesting in your xml, you should use `XmlElelement` (as for every other property)  instead of `XmlArrayItem`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere read the paragraph after and I explain. "i keep getting 0 items after deserializing"